# detect two consecutive lines matching a pattern with sed

Tags: sed

I am looking for two consecutive lines matching a certain pattern, say containing word 'pat' using sed and have noticed that I am able to detect it sometimes with this command:

```
sed -n 'N; /.*pat.*\n.*pat.*/p'
```

but this command fails if the line numbers for the duplicates are not of the same parity and I assume it's because we're searching lines 1+2, 3+4, 5+6 etc.. if this is the case, what would be the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why does it need to be `sed`? May I suggest `awk`?

```
awk '{/pat/?f++:f=0} f==2' file
```

If `pat` is found, increment `f` with `1`
If `pat` is not found, reset `f` to `0`
If `f==2` print the line.

Comment: Is this correct? I think it needs an else for when we don't match pat?

Comment: Yes, I see that, will fix

Comment: @PalaceChan This should do.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '$!N;/pattern.*\n.*pattern/p;D' file
```

This keeps 2 lines in the pattern space and prints both of them out if the regexp matches.

Comment: It will not only print second line with pattern, but also first line too.  If there are three lines with pattern, it will print first,second,second and third line.

Comment: @Jotne I thought that was intended, if not change the `p` to a `P` or to `{p;d}`.

Comment: Changing to `P` only prints first hits.  I assume he like the second line found if two pattern comes within two lines (I may be wrong). It may be ok to print first line if there are two line after each other with same patter.