# Delete all consecutive lines with sed, but not an isolated one

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a log file which looks like the following text:

```
...
5 files analysed in 98 ms
7 files analysed in 654 ms
   error1: ....
   error2: ....
   error3: ....
21 files analysed in 345 ms
3 files analysed in 78 ms
6 files analysed in 55 ms
...
```

I am looking forward to using "sed" or "awk" in order to remove all consecutive lines containing the pattern "files analysed in", but not the one above the useful information.

```
7 files analysed in 654 ms
   error1: ....
   error2: ....
   error3: ....
```

I tried some tricks from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22644404/detect-two-consecutive-lines-matching-a-pattern-with-sed). But nothing is working like I would like to. The number of errors is not always the same.

How could I proceed?

Comment: can you post more exact `pattern` value and `some useful information` ?

Comment: What do you mean bu "But the first and the last consecutive patterns remain."  It seems you want to only get the lines that match "some useful information" + 1 line above, is that understanding correct?

Comment: I edited the post as I wasn"t clear, the information is written on several lines actually.
In fact, the log file is like: 
"4 files analysed in 53 ms
12 files analysed in 265 ms
     error: a is not initialised...
     error : b is not used...
     ...
6 files analysed in 85 ms
..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -v "files analysed in" -B 1
```

select everything that doesn't have the pattern, but provide one line of context before each match

Comment: I guess that the `...` refer to some other lines before and after this section of the file, which presumably shouldn't be printed either.

Comment: Indeed, sorry, I edited the post. I have some extra information, and the useful information is printed through several lines actually

Comment: the grep -v will work if the useful information is multiline, but won't work if there are other lines that don't match the pattern but aren't useful either (though I'm not sure how we'd recognise them)

Answer (score 0):

with `awk`

```
$ awk '/pattern/{p=$0} !/pattern/{print p; print}' file

foo3 pattern foo4
   some useful information
```

you can also exit after the first match.